# `duplicate symbol _main` Swift AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I'm attempting to transition my iOS application to Swift. Everything was going great, until I tried replacing my AppDelegate.m/.h with a .swift equivalent. Now, when building, I get the following errors:

```
Ld /Users/ruben/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bowdoin_Dining-eevtozmixiiwpkdhanzlqfsrhfxr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Bowdoin\ Dining.app/Bowdoin\ Dining normal i386
    cd "/Users/ruben/Workspace/Development/Objective-C/Bowdoin Dining"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode6-Beta2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode6-Beta2.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode6-Beta2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode6-Beta2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk -L/Users/ruben/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bowdoin_Dining-eevtozmixiiwpkdhanzlqfsrhfxr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/ruben/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bowdoin_Dining-eevtozmixiiwpkdhanzlqfsrhfxr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/ruben/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bowdoin_Dining-eevtozmixiiwpkdhanzlqfsrhfxr/Build/Intermediates/Bowdoin\ Dining.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Bowdoin\ Dining.build/Objects-normal/i386/Bowdoin\ Dining.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -lxml2 -lswift_stdlib_core -L/Applications/Xcode6-Beta2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -force_load -Xlinker /Applications/Xcode6-Beta2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphonesimulator.a -Xlinker -sectalign -Xlinker __SWIFT -Xlinker __ast -Xlinker 4 -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __SWIFT -Xlinker __ast -Xlinker /Users/ruben/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bowdoin_Dining-eevtozmixiiwpkdhanzlqfsrhfxr/Build/Intermediates/Bowdoin\ Dining.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Bowdoin\ Dining.build/Objects-normal/i386/BowdoinDining.swiftmodule -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=8.0 -lz.1.2.5 -framework MobileCoreServices -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/ruben/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bowdoin_Dining-eevtozmixiiwpkdhanzlqfsrhfxr/Build/Intermediates/Bowdoin\ Dining.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Bowdoin\ Dining.build/Objects-normal/i386/Bowdoin\ Dining_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/ruben/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bowdoin_Dining-eevtozmixiiwpkdhanzlqfsrhfxr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Bowdoin\ Dining.app/Bowdoin\ Dining
```

And:

```
duplicate symbol _main in:
    /Users/ruben/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bowdoin_Dining-eevtozmixiiwpkdhanzlqfsrhfxr/Build/Intermediates/Bowdoin Dining.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Bowdoin Dining.build/Objects-normal/i386/AppDelegate.o
    /Users/ruben/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bowdoin_Dining-eevtozmixiiwpkdhanzlqfsrhfxr/Build/Intermediates/Bowdoin Dining.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Bowdoin Dining.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

That this error seems so generic isn't all that helpful...But it's all I've really got. It seemed to happen after I switched my `import "AppDelegate.h` int `main.m` to `import "MyAppName-Swift.h"`. Does anyone know why this would happen? Thanks.

Comment: Can you confirm it still works if you remove these changes?  Because if not it's most likely an IDE / debugging error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can ditch main.m entirely. Just add `@UIApplicationMain` on the line above your app delegate's class declaration to specify the entry point of the application.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and deleting main.m solved it. In my case I was converting an objective-c app to swift and have a mixture at present.